# Emacs disable mouse-1 in dired

Tags: emacs, mouseevent, dired

In Emacs 23.2.1 in Dired mode the mouse-1 (left mouse button) performs `visit file in other window`. It also changes shape to a finger and highlights the filename when cursor hovers over the filename. How do I disable both `visit file` and filename highlighting ? I want mouse-1 to do its usual stuff: selecting text.

I can still select text if I start by clicking down in an area outside the filename or directory name. But I only want the filename marked, and not have a space in front included.

Comment: Looking in `mouse.el` I just learned that by default I **can** select part of the filename in dired mode: I just need to click-down and **move** the cursor. However, because of the filename highlighting it is difficult to see what I am selecting. Still want this 'feature' killed: which normal person opens a file by clicking on it with the mouse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just turn off `mouse-1-click-follows-link` by customizing it to `nil`.  (You can also set it to a long time-limit value.)

Or if you want to do that only for Dired buffers, you can do this:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (set (make-local-variable 'mouse-1-click-follows-link) nil)))
```

But it is typically better to name a function that you use on a hook (it's easier to remove it, for one thing):

```
(defun foo ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'mouse-1-click-follows-link) nil)))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'foo)
```

If you have a recent version of Emacs, where `setq-local` is defined, then you can use just `(setq-local mouse-1-click-follows-link nil)` in the hook function, in place of `(set (make-local-variable 'mouse-1-click-follows-link) nil)`

Comment: Main problem fixed. However filename is still highlighted making it difficult to see which part I am selecting. By overwriting an internal  `mouse.el` function by adding `(defun dired-insert-set-properties (beg end) nil)` highlighting and finger-cursor also disappeared. Is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: I'd suggest you just customize face `highlight`, which is used for the highlighting provided by property `mouse-face`, so you can see better. The highlighting is there for a reason: you can click **`mouse-2`** (not just `mouse-1`) or hit **`RET`** on a link (highlighted text) to visit a file or directory. (And if you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then the whole line is highlighted, which helps align information by eye.) If you really do not want the highlighting then yes, just change `dired-insert-set-properties`.